# How can I get rid of an Underfull \hbox message in my macro?

Tags: macros, line-breaking, warnings

I can't find the reason for getting this message:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

This is my test case:

```
\newcommand{\ruler}{\noindent\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}\\}
\newcommand{\rulercap}[1]{\ruler{\Large #1\hfill\\}\ruler}

\rulercap{test caption}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second call to `\ruler` ends with a linebreak, but the line is empty, which creates an underfull hbox.  Do this instead:

```
\newcommand{\ruler}{\noindent\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\newcommand{\rulercap}[1]{\ruler\\{\Large #1\hfill\\}\ruler}

\rulercap{test caption}
```